# Нужно объяснить действий цикла for (у меня есть решение, нужно его объяснить)

Tags: javascript

Задача: заменить буквы на цифры, встретив букву «a», добавьте к результирующей строке «4». встретив «e», добавьте «3», встретив «i»,
добавьте «1», а встретив «o» — «0».

Решение я нашёл задачи, но объяснить я себе не смог что мы выполняем в данном примере.

Зачем нам `else { output += input[i]; }` не понимаю как он работает и действует.
Если можете, то объясните всю работу кода.

```js
let input = "javascript is awesome";
let output = '';

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i] === 'a') {
    output += 4;
  }  else if (input[i] === 'e') {
    output += 3;
  }  else if (input[i] === 'i') {
    output += 1;
  }  else if (input[i] === 'o') {
    output += 0;
  }
    else {
  output += input[i];
  }
}
console.log(output)
```

Всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: "Зачем нам `else { output += input[i]; }`" - уберите и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: @Igor это очень замечательно, что вы понимаете, что происходит в коде.
Но я только изучаю js и не понимаю некоторые решения.

output += input[i]; 
Зачем мы output  плюсуем к input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас есть строка

```
let input = "javascript is awesome";
```

Циклом **for** мы проходимся по каждому символу.
Сначала идёт символ **j**
Проверяем его в условиях

```
if (input[i] === 'a') { **// не равен**
    output += 4; 
  }  else if (input[i] === 'e') { **// не равен**
    output += 3;
  }  else if (input[i] === 'i') { **// не равен**
    output += 1;
  }  else if (input[i] === 'o') { **// не равен**
    output += 0;
  }
```

Поскольку символ не подходит ни одному условию, поэтому мы записываем символ **j** в переменную output.

Если же условие будет истинно и у нас будет символ равен одной из букв **a, e, i, o**, то мы запишем 4, 3, 1, 0 в переменную output.

С `else { output += input[i]; }` получится такой результат: **j4v4scr1pt 1s 4w3s0m3**

Если же убрать строку кода `else { output += input[i]; }`, то будет такой результат:  **44114303**, поскольку в переменную output будут записываться только числа.

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек.
Вы поняли мою боль.

Comment: @Evgeniy, вот онлайн-учебник по [javascript](https://learn.javascript.ru)

Comment: спасибо, я знаком с данным учебником, но некоторые объяснения для меня не понятны в нем и я решил начать с книги 
" JavaScript для детей. 
Самоучитель по программированию 
Морган Ник " говорят хорошая книга, я учусь по ней, нравится.

Comment: @Evgeniy, удачи в изучении)

Comment: Спасибо, @VDone вам того же)

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам код попроще.

```js
const map = { 'a': '4', 'e': '3', 'i': '1', 'o': '0' };
const input = "javascript is awesome";
const output = input.split('').map(c => map[c] || c).join('');

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение.
Оно пока что сложно для меня, но со временем я его пойму.